# Choose by name et get the id in md-autocomplete input in angular 4 material application

Tags: angular, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have an angular 4 application with material design. In this application I have a form with an autocomplete field.

This is my html code :

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="text" mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="project" [formControl]="projectCtrl" placeholder="Choose a project" [(ngModel)]="selectProjectForNewCollab" name="selectProjectForNewCollab">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-autocomplete #project="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let project of filteredProjects | async" [value]="project.name">
      {{ project.name }}
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

And my ts code :

```js
console.log("project = " + this.selectProjectForNewCollab);
```

So, I have `projects` with 3 fields : `{id: "1", name: "test", photo: "test"}`.
I want to choose a project by its name but get back the id in return.
Actually, I have choose with the name but I get the name at the end. If I change the `[value]="project.id"`, I get the id but it's teh id which is displayed in the input.

So, do you know how I can do to get the id but choose by name and display the name in the input ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have separate `control` and `display` for `md-autocomplete`. `md-autocomplete` provides `displayWith` api which can be used to pick which field to show in dropdown/selected field.

For your code, it would look something like following:

html:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Project" 
         [(ngModel)]="selectProjectForNewCollab" (ngModelChange)="setProject(project)"
         [mdAutocomplete]="project" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #project="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let project of filteredStates | async" [value]="project" >
    {{ project.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

In component.ts, have to add the `displanFn`:

```
displayFn(project): string {
    console.log(project);
      return project ? project.name : project;
}
```

Please note that, in html, the binding is with the whole object now `[value]="project"`, which allows to show one property, but get all properties of the object behind the scenes, from there, you can pick the `id` of the selected item.

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/c5gBS1mpPrD9Hyonahyv?p=preview)

Comment: But how can I get the id of the object to send in order to filter data? when I change the [value]="project"  to [value]="project.id" the autocomplete doesn't show the options.